# How to keep character count in Python and Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a Twitter automation tool and I'm using Tkinter.  I have a simple text box and I want to keep track of each character typed in.  I'm using an event, but each event is a separate...event.  For example, in this code, I print out the event count and it's always one.  Is there a way to keep track of the count so it counts up to 140 just like Twitter does?

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font


def key_detector(event):
    count = len(event.char)
    print(count)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

bottom_frame = Frame(root)
bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

font_size = font.Font(size=16)

character_count = Label(bottom_frame, text="0/140", bg="white", fg="black")
character_count.pack(side=RIGHT)

tweet_box = Text(bottom_frame, fg="blue", width="50", height="5", borderwidth="2", relief="ridge")
tweet_box['font'] = font_size
tweet_box.bind("<Key>", key_detector)
tweet_box.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady="10")

root.mainloop()
```

Once I figure it out, I'll simply pass a string of the count to character_count Label.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: A count of `<Key>` events tells you nothing about the length of the text - what if the key was Delete, for example?  Or if text was pasted in?  You simply want to get the contents of the `Text` and then get the `len()` of that.

Comment: Good point.  I didn't think about that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event.char` is **a single** character entered that caused the event.

Here is the correct function:

```
def key_detector(event):
    count = len(tweet_box.get("1.0", "end"))
    print(count)
```

Next time you should try `print(event.char)` to see what exactly you are doing.

Comment: THANKS!!!  This is way easier than the possibilities I was thinking in my head.